# Using NULL in WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure takes an optional parameter like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
(       
     @P1 varchar(255) = NULL
)
AS
     SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = @P1
```

When `@P1` is `NULL`, I want to select all records. One obvious way is to use `IF` here, but I'd like to do this in a single SQL statement. Can someone suggest a clever way to achieve that? I'm thinking on the lines of using `ISNULL()` or `MyField = MyField`. Have tried a few ways too, but the fact that `NULL = NULL` is not `True` is the main blockade here.

Comment: You should take a look at this article about this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE @P1 IS NULL OR MyField = @P1
```

Another possibly more efficient approach using `If...Else`:

```
if(@P1 IS NULL)
        begin
             SELECT * FROM MyTable
        End
Else
        begin
             SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = @P1
        End
```

Comment: mmm... won't that fail when `@P1` has a value?

Comment: @dotNET: if `@P1` has a value `@P1 IS NULL` returns `false` and `MyField = @P1` will be checked for every row. Otherwise all rows are returned since `@P1 IS NULL` already returns `true`.

Comment: @dotNET - Did you atleast execute the query. Learn how `OR` operator works Btw am the first one to Upvote

Comment: Funny someone gives a correct answer and the author of the question asks wont that fail...well how do you know if it fails if you are the one who is asking the question?  To top it off the author asks who upvoted the answer????  Come on people this guy is taking time out of his day to help you and these are the responses you give.  RTFM sorry.

Comment: @JonH - Aggreeeed... got irritated by seeing his comments. People like  this should be sacked

Comment: The first approach would be my recommendation. Otherwise you are likely going to end up with bad cached execution plans.

Comment: oops. my mistake. i typed the query instead of copy/pasting and misread the first condition. A bunch of apologies. I'll take back my comments. End of a long stressful day in my part of the world, so probably I was not at my best.

Comment: @SeanLange: If performance is a real issue he could split this procedure into two smaller, one without and one with parameter which are called from the `If`...`Else`.

Comment: Performance should be totally acceptable using your first method. Just need to add the OPTION RECOMPILE and it should be fine.

Comment: @SeanLange: use OPTION RECOMPILE only if it's really necessary. Otherwise you might hurt your CPU needlessly.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE MyField = ISNULL(@P1, MyField)`

That should get what you need.

Comment: This was obvious, but it fails because of the `NULL = NULL` not being True in SQL, as noted in the question.

Comment: @dotNET that isn't going to fail. There is not a NULL = NULL comparison happening in this code.

Comment: @SeanLange: What if `MyField` is NULL in a particular row and `@P1` is NULL too?

Comment: It isn't the way I would code it but it works if the column is not nullable. :)

Comment: `WHERE ISNULL(MyField, 1) = ISNULL(@P1, MyField)` ?? Ugly though. And it will leave out records where MyField is null

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have given you direct solutions, but there is something you need to work with null:

You cannot use equality (`=`) and inequality (`<>`) operators with `NULL` because SQL treats `NULL` as a distinct value that never equals anything (even itself – `null = null` is false!).

Rather use `value is null` and `value is not null` to check for null or not null respectively.